# Multiple JQuery actions based on timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a testimonial box that has the testimonial within it, and then I have icons indicating whom provided the testimonial underneath. Connected to the box and right above the icon is a little arrow that can be generated via CSS or an image.

Every 5 seconds, it should change the testimonial content via a fade-in/fade-out, the little image should slide to the right, and the icon should fade to a colored version of the icon. At the end of the loop (when it reaches the 5th one), the arrow should slide all the way to the left and the loop should begin again.

I'm not too familiar with how I can do this with a loop efficiently, or how to time it. I know the basics of how I can fade it in and whatnot, but I'm lost on the rest.

[image]
Thank you very much!

Comment: I would personally create an object that has the testimonial text and the location for the image (ie, the margin-left it needs to be at). Run a setTimeout to move next, if the current position is > length of object go back to start. It could also store the location for the image files for swapping them from color to black and white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) is what you're looking for.

```
var counter = 0;
var repeat = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);

function myFunc()
{
    //increment counter
    counter++;

    if (counter == 5)
    {
        //reset counter
        counter = 0;
        //time to slide all the way to the left
    }
    else
    {
        slide one image to the right
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll need to create a `setInterval` function that executes another function every 5000ms. The other function needs to loop through an array of your testimonials and increment by 1 after each setTimeout execution.

```
var testimonials = ['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3', 'test 4', 'test 5'];
var counter = 0;
var time = 5000; // modify this using milliseconds
var timer = window.setInterval(swapTestimony, time);

function swapTestimony() {
    counter += 1;
    if (counter === testimonials.length + 1) {
        counter = 1;
    }
    // do your animations here
    console.log(testimonials[counter - 1]);
}
```